# How to treat endogeneity of the dependent variable in this predictive logit model?

Tags: regression, logistic, endogeneity

I built a predictive logit model to measure the effect of different factors on winning in soccer. Where the dependent variable ($y_i$) is winning (1: win, 0: draw or lose), and the controls ($x_i$) are different sport statistics (ball possession (%), completed passes, fouls, shots on target, etc.):
$$log \left( \frac{p}{1-p} \right)=x_i^T \beta + u_i$$

My problem is that, when team A is loosing, then team B is winning by definition. Therefore, the dependent variable ($y_i$) is not unbiased by the performance of the other team. How can I solve this endogeneity problem in variable $y_t$? Is including a dummy of the opponent team's winning status a good idea?

Comment: How many teams do you have in the dataset?  Are the different factors (possession, fouls, etc.) match-specific, meaning you have data for both teams for each match?  Are these values averages over the course of the match, or do you have data from multiple time points (e.g., if team A had 3 corners and 75% possession by half time, what's the probability of winning at full time?). I'd be interested in seeing how the data are set up